# Getting error after running a simple Kotlin Script on VS Code

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, visual-studio-code

I ran this code on VS Code Kotlin

```
fun main() {
    println(“Hello World!”)
}
```

This is what I receive after running this code

```
Week1.kt:1:4: error: expecting function name or receiver type
fun fun main() {
```

This is the version that I am running.

```
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.5.31 (JRE 17+0
```

Any thoughts

Comment: as I remeber single SMS may have only 140 chars - how long is your message? Different systems may use different code for `new line`. LInux uses code `10`, as I remeber Mac was using `13` but now it may use `10` and Windows uses both values together `1013`. Maybe some codes has special meaning in SMS.

Comment: not sure if you're also having another problem, but you have the literal "Hello World" in "smart quotes" instead of normal quotes. You might want to try replacing them.